# apparmor profile for pdns-recursor blocks to start the pdns-recursor service on systemd

Tags: server, systemd, apparmor

When I generate the apparmor profile with aa-genprof for /usr/sbin/pdns_recursor everything seems to be OK. But apparmor blocks the service startup even in complain mode.
I have launched a brand new AWS EC2 ubuntu instance to check it.
Ubuntu16 runs well, but Ubuntu18 and Ubuntu20 shows the issue.
I think it should be a systemd relevant problem, but couldn't find the root cause.

```
root@ip-172-31-3-245:/home/ubuntu# aa-genprof /usr/sbin/pdns_recursor

root@ip-172-31-3-245:/home/ubuntu# aa-complain /usr/sbin/pdns_recursor 
root@ip-172-31-3-245:/home/ubuntu# systemctl stop pdns-recursor.service
root@ip-172-31-3-245:/home/ubuntu# systemctl start pdns-recursor.service  # it blocks till timeout

root@ip-172-31-3-245:/home/ubuntu# aa-disable /usr/sbin/pdns_recursor    
root@ip-172-31-3-245:/home/ubuntu# systemctl stop pdns-recursor.service
root@ip-172-31-3-245:/home/ubuntu# systemctl start pdns-recursor.service  # it runs fluently
```

I cleaned up the /var/log/kern.log and /var/log/syslog too to see the messages. This is the relevant /var/log/syslog :

```
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 systemd[1]: Starting PowerDNS Recursor...
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: PowerDNS Recursor 4.1.1 (C) 2001-2017 PowerDNS.COM BV
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Using 64-bits mode. Built using gcc 7.3.0.
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: PowerDNS comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it according to the terms of the GPL version 2.
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Reading random entropy from '/dev/urandom'
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: If using IPv6, please raise sysctl net.ipv6.route.max_size, currently set to 4096 which is < 16384
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: NOT using IPv6 for outgoing queries - set 'query-local-address6=::' to enable
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Only allowing queries from: 127.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8, 100.64.0.0/10, 169.254.0.0/16, 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, ::1/128, fc00::/7, fe80::/10
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 kernel: [ 1247.120388] audit: type=1400 audit(1593796506.631:2170): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/pdns_recursor" name="run/systemd/journal/dev-log" pid=13633 comm="pdns_recursor" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 kernel: [ 1247.120988] audit: type=1400 audit(1593796506.631:2171): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/pdns_recursor" name="run/systemd/journal/dev-log" pid=13633 comm="pdns_recursor" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=0 ouid=0
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Will not send queries to: 127.0.0.0/8, 10.0.0.0/8, 100.64.0.0/10, 169.254.0.0/16, 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12, ::1/128, fc00::/7, fe80::/10, 0.0.0.0/8, 192.0.0.0/24, 192.0.2.0/24, 198.51.100.0/24, 203.0.113.0/24, 240.0.0.0/4, ::/96, ::ffff:0:0/96, 100::/64, 2001:db8::/32, 0.0.0.0, ::
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: PowerDNS Recursor itself will distribute queries over threads
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Inserting rfc 1918 private space zones
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Listening for UDP queries on 127.0.0.1:53
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Enabled TCP data-ready filter for (slight) DoS protection
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Listening for TCP queries on 127.0.0.1:53
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Set effective group id to 115
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Set effective user id to 111
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Launching 3 threads
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 kernel: [ 1247.144789] audit: type=1400 audit(1593796506.655:2172): apparmor="ALLOWED" operation="sendmsg" info="Failed name lookup - disconnected path" error=-13 profile="/usr/sbin/pdns_recursor" name="run/systemd/notify" pid=13633 comm="pdns_recursor" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=111 ouid=0
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Done priming cache with root hints
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Done priming cache with root hints
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Enabled 'epoll' multiplexer
Jul  3 17:15:06 ip-172-31-3-245 pdns_recursor[13633]: Done priming cache with root hints
Jul  3 17:16:36 ip-172-31-3-245 systemd[1]: pdns-recursor.service: Start operation timed out. Terminating.
Jul  3 17:16:36 ip-172-31-3-245 systemd[1]: pdns-recursor.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Jul  3 17:16:36 ip-172-31-3-245 systemd[1]: Failed to start PowerDNS Recursor.
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to extend the generated profile as [Christian Boltz mentioned in 2016](https://ubuntu-bugs.narkive.com/6qWyT4l1/bug-1568485-new-kernel-audit-type-1400-audit-1460259033-648-34-apparmor-denied-operation-sendmsg) to add

```
flags=(attach_disconnected)
```

to the generated rule.